# Extending a class with an other namespace with the same ClassName

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to use namespaces. I want to extend a class inside a different namespace. The name of the class is the same. Example:

Parent:

```
namespace Base;

class Section extends Skeleton {

protected $id;

protected $title;

protected $stylesheet;
}
```

Child:

```
namespace Base2;
use \Base\Section;

class Section 
    extends \Base\Section {

}
```

It is an application which uses Doctrine 2 and Zend Framework. The Skeleton class used by Base/Section is just an abstract class that contains the magic methods (__get, _set, etc).

When I try to instantiate a \Base2\Section class it throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Base2\Section because the name is 
already in use in /var/www/test/application/Models/Base2/Section.php 
on line 7
```

Any idea's?

Comment: Isn't it a little bit confusing to have such naming scheme?

Comment: Yes it is, but it is not the real naming scheme. Only the Section part is real. The namespaces are just random.

Comment: @Rene: Are you sure that they are not instead _arbitrary_?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just use fully qualified name

```
namespace Base2;

class Section 
    extends \Base\Section {
}
```

Or aliasing

```
namespace Base2;
use \Base\Section as BSection;

class Section 
    extends BSection {
}
```

Answer (score 13):

when you say

```
use \Base\Section
```

you are pulling the Section class into your current scope, causing a conflict when you want to create a new class called Section. just omit the use statement.

Comment: Right, class name with name can be confusing. Every time I see this type of code, I need to think a bit about it.